# MongoDB Pymongo issue

Tags: python, mongodb, find, pymongo

I'm trying to make a python script that finds the first entry in a mongodb collection, to try it out, but everytime i try to launch it, i get this error log. Thanks for helping! And by the way, don't worry,  and  are not in the code, these are just placeholders.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

myclient = 
pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<MY USERNAME>:<MY PASSWORD>@cluster0.tzdil.mongodb.net/test")
mydb = myclient["db1"]
mycol = mydb["coll1"]
x = mycol.find_one()
print(x)
```

The error log :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\pafk\Documents\code\MongoDB\readDB.py", line 7, in 
> x = mycol.find_one()
> File "C:\Users\pafk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1114, in find_one
> for result in cursor.limit(-1):
> File "C:\Users\pafk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1159, in next
> if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
> File "C:\Users\pafk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1057, in _refresh
> self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
> File "C:\Users\pafk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1603, in _ensure_session
> return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
> File "C:\Users\pafk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1553, in __start_session
> server_session = self._get_server_session()
> File "C:\Users\pafk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1589, in _get_server_session
> return self._topology.get_server_session()
> File "C:\Users\pafk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 530, in get_server_session
> session_timeout = self._check_session_support()
> File "C:\Users\pafk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 514, in _check_session_support
> self._select_servers_loop(
> File "C:\Users\pafk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 216, in _select_servers_loop
> raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster0-shard-00-02.tzdil.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129),cluster0-shard-00-01.tzdil.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129),cluster0-shard-00-00.tzdil.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 61b23eef1f57f5d7372ad4b3, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-00.tzdil.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-00.tzdil.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-01.tzdil.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-01.tzdil.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-02.tzdil.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-02.tzdil.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)')>]>
> PS C:\Users\pafk\Documents\code\MongoDB>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/keep-getting-serverselectiontimeouterror/126190

> If you are suddenly encountering problems with TLS certificate validation when connecting to Atlas, this is likely due to older root certificates used by Let’s Encrypt expiring on Sept 30, 2021. MongoDB Atlas uses Let’s Encrypt to sign Atlas cluster TLS certificates.

> This validation issue is on the client side of the connection, not the server. Your Atlas cluster certificates are still valid, but your local trust stores do not contain the new root certificate required for verification.

> Common root certificates are generally included in O/S updates, but in some cases you may need to manually update trust stores used by your O/S or application environment.

> For more information, please see: Which certificate authority signs MongoDB Atlas cluster TLS certificates?.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).